# These permissions give an error in Android version 33, write permissions

Tags: java, android

I have researched a lot, but it gives an error during the process because it does not create a file. I had this problem after upgrading to Android 33. I am sharing the error I get.

Video codec error                                                                                                 android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffffed

```
  void createDirectory(){
            String path = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsoluteFile()+"/"+getString(R.string.app_name)); // set your desired path here
            File directory = new File(path);
    
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                if (directory.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "Directory created successfully");
                } else {
                    Log.e("MyApp", "Failed to create directory");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Directory already exists");
            }
    
        }


    private void requestPermissions() {
        String[] permissions = new String[0];
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            } else {
                permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            }

        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                } else {
                    // pickImageFromGallery();
                    isPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                } else {
                    // pickImageFromGallery();
                    isPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            //pickImageFromGallery();
            isPermissionGranted = true;
        }

    }
```